# Assignment does not return void

Tags: java, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

I found this piece of code on [Google Guava Github](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/StandardTable.java), and I cannot figure out why on the 5th line the `rowMap` method does not return void if the condition is satisfied :

```
private transient @MonotonicNonNull Map<R, Map<C, V>> rowMap;

public Map<R, Map<C, V>> rowMap() {
  Map<R, Map<C, V>> result = rowMap;
  return (result == null) ? rowMap = createRowMap() : result;
}

Map<R, Map<C, V>> createRowMap() {
  return new RowMap();
}
```

Wouldn't this line be equivalent to :

```
if (result == null) {
  return rowMap = createRowMap();
} else {
  return result;
}
```

And then the assignment to rowMap would return void. What did I miss?

Comment: Does `return new RowMap()`work?

Comment: what do you mean: return void?

Comment: Because assignment works from right to left, `rowMap` is assigned the result of `createRowMap()` and _then_ `rowMap` is returned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What did I miss?

The fact that the result of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned. :-) So in that code, the result of the call to `createRowMap` is assigned to `rowMap` **and** returned as the result of the `rowMap` function. It's just like:

```
a = b = 42;
```

...sets `b` to `42` and then sets `a` to `42` (the result of the `b = 42` assignment).

The effect is the same as if the code were written like this instead:

```
public Map<R, Map<C, V>> rowMap() {
  Map<R, Map<C, V>> result = rowMap;
  if (result != null) {
    return result;
  }
  rowMap = createRowMap();
  return rowMap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation result of assignment expression `varibale = value` is `value`, try:

```
int a;
System.out.println(a = 1); // 1
```

So it equals:

```
if (result == null) {
    rowMap = createRowMap();
    return rowMap;
}
```

[See jls for more:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.1)

> When an expression in a program is evaluated (executed), the result
>   denotes one of three things:
>
> - A variable (§4.12) (in C, this would be called an lvalue)
> - A value (§4.2, §4.3)
> - Nothing (the expression is said to be void)
>
> ...
>
> An expression denotes nothing **if and only if** it is a method invocation
>   (§15.12) that invokes a method that does not return a value, that is,
>   a method declared void (§8.4).